# How do I improve performance of SSIS calling a WCF service?

Tags: performance, wcf, ssis

**Edit**
I've discovered that the service is not actually performing any database calls when running my process but it does for the normal application. I am going to troubleshoot a problem with my SSIS package / code under the assumption that something is silently failing or looping there it shouldn't.

**Original Question**
I have an SSIS package that has a table of user accounts. I need to loop through them (386,000 rows) and call a WCF service to create the users in our system. The WCF call is sub-second but even at 1/2 second this process would take over 50 hours. To improve through-put I modified the package to divide the result set into 5 batches and process them asynchronously.

[image: Sequence Container]

The process works and I get the expected 1/5 run time in Visual Studio debugging. Problem is that after 40,000ish users my VS will crash.

[image: Progress results]

So, I attempted an execution using the SQL Server Execute Package Utility but the iteration run time seems to be growing and is destroying any improvement that I made.

**Execution start**
[image: Execution start]
**Execution after 2 hours of processing**
[image: Execution after 2 hrs]

Any solution to my problem would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Images don't seem to be working.

Comment: I see the image problem now that I've opened a new browser. Is there a pastebin like site that I might be able to move these to so everyone can see them?

Comment: Can you export your data to xml or json then pass the xml or json to your wcf service, then let the wcf process the data ? I know that it is a lot of data, but still better that looping through 300 000 records and for each record calling the wcf service

Comment: As of this moment, I can't change the service. It only has a single method for me to hit and pass in one user at a time. It might be possible to get approval to change it but it'd have to be one of the only good options.

Comment: I see - kind of a bummer that the service cannot be modified, but I understand. Have you tried adding a pause in between each successful call to the wcf service ? http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2011/04/pause-in-ssis.html

Comment: See my edits, I think the problem is elsewhere and that I won't know about performance until I correct the immediate issue.